# sh commands in .somefile

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am learning about the sh command and was the following instructions, and would like to understand what it does and its effects.

//.devrun.sh

```
CLUSTER_DISCOVERY_URL=mongodb://localhost/service-discovery \
CLUSTER_SERVICE="search" \
CLUSTER_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:$PORT \
ROOT_URL=http://www.mydomainname.com \
meteor --port $PORT
```

The command to run it:
`PORT=<port number> sh .devrun.sh`

Are these environment variables to export? what about those "\"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` character, in context, is a "continuation" character. The shell interprets each line as one line because of the continuation character.

Evidently, `meteor` needs a definition of certain environment variables, and these were defined in the command line: `CLUSTER_DISCOVERY_URL`, `CLUSTER_SERVICE`, `CLUSTER_ENDPOINT_URL`, and `ROOT_URL`. In addition, another environment variable is defined on the command line: `PORT`.

All of these variables are defined before running `.devrun.sh`.

Comment: (with the assumed typo of a leading `$` before `PORT` in the question)

Comment: @JeffSchaller typo fixed. thx